# Winforms label fine in designer, cut off when running

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing an app using Winforms. I have a label in my design view that looks fine
[image: Fine]

But when I run the program, the label is cut off on the right side

[image: NotFine]

I have the label set to AutoSize, any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Do you change the label in code?  Or set AutoSize to false somewhere?  Is there a panel on top of it?  Maybe anchored so it looks different then the designer?  What happens when you resize?

Comment: The label's text and AutoSize property is only set in the designer. The only other control next to it is the text box below it, but deleting the text box does not help. It's anchor setting is the default (Top,Left). If I turn AutoSize off and widen the label, then it fixes the text, though for translation purposes I would rather have it resize automatically. 

I assume that my system font is bigger than the font in the designer, though one would think that the AutoSizing would happen at runtime, not design time.

Comment: Well to be sure you can change your font to the system font and see how the label looks.  WinForms is not as _agile_ as WPF or some other UI development tools

Comment: Can you turn on its Border to see if the label or the text is affected?

Comment: I had to move on with the project. The workaround that I found was to just turn off AutoSize and then give the label plenty of room. In the end, it seems like a Microsoft bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the "Anchor" setting to only anchor to the left *or* the right, but not to both the left *and* the right.

[image: WinForms Anchor Setting]

When the label is anchored both left and right, if the outside container is re-sized for any reason (e.g., click and drag window border, or re-sized in code), the label ends up getting cut off for some reason when AutoSize is used.